# Error Deploying to Heroku Play 2.2 app

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0

I think i am having a problem in my Procfile. The deploy is compiled successfully but the app does not start with this message --

```
2014-03-27T14:17:06.465302+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ea0e14d by xxxx@gmail.com
2014-03-27T14:17:06.465378+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v10 created by xxxx@gmail.com
2014-03-27T14:17:14.091032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/enigmatic-dusk-7498 -Dhttp.port=32253`
2014-03-27T14:17:15.199466+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/universal/stage/bin/enigmatic-dusk-7498: No such file or directory
2014-03-27T14:17:16.511169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-03-27T14:17:16.521177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

The procfile reads:

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/enigmatic-dusk-7498 -Dhttp.port=$PORT
```

which i guess is the standard for play 2.2 onwards.
What is wrong? enigmatic dusk is the name given by heroku to my app. my local name is different.

EDIT:

As per some suggestions i tried changing the procfile to my local app-name.

New Procfile -

```
web: target/universal/stage/bin/ExampleBootStrap -Dhttp.port=$PORT
```

Still it fails.

```
2014-03-27T17:58:12.527528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/ExampleBootStrap -Dhttp.port=38392`
2014-03-27T17:58:13.948429+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/universal/stage/bin/ExampleBootStrap: No such file or directory
2014-03-27T17:58:15.608461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2014-03-27T17:58:15.621947+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-03-27T17:58:15.620997+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-27T17:58:27.265083+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-03-27T17:58:24.366648+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/ExampleBootStrap -Dhttp.port=33223`
2014-03-27T17:58:25.666535+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: target/universal/stage/bin/ExampleBootStrap: No such file or directory
2014-03-27T17:58:27.250296+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
```

Answer (score 4):

In your procfile, you must replace enigmatic-dusk-7498 with the name of your play project **in lower case letters**, not you heroku app.

Comment: Tried this. See above for edits / details. Still not working.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. I tried with all possible Procfile configuration but still no luck. Please can you guide me in that ?

Comment: Create a new thread with build.sbt file +  Procfile + heroku logs and give here the link ;)