# Java Play! todolist tutorial; can't push to production on Heroku. Error H10

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

I'm new to web development and I've just finished the Java Play! todolist tutorial:
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/JavaTodoList

The app was running locally, however I can't get it to run on Heroku. I get an H10 error code.

Some have suggested:

```
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
$ heroku restart
```

But when run the rake I get a "Rake aborted! No rake file found!" error. Is this a rails thing?

Thanks for any help.

[EDIT] FIXED - See my comment response! Needed to update the procfile.

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h10-app-crashed (from Google search for "Heroku H10"). As for the rake file error, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q="Rake+aborted%21+No+rake+file+found%21"+db%3Amigrate).

Comment: I guess I didn't read high enough up in the log. It's telling me, "target/universal/stage/bin/{your-app-name-here} no such file or directory. Apparently I have to change that in the Procfile. Let's see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the H10 error wasn't very specific, which is why I asked the question. Apparently, I just didn't read high enough up into my log file. If I had kept reading I would've found, "target/universal/stage/bin/{your-app-name-here} no such file or directory"

Apparently I forgot to change some text in my Procfile.  Thanks to the link below for the answer:
[Error Deploying to Heroku Play 2.2 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690433/error-deploying-to-heroku-play-2-2-app)